# Using the Mongoose $or operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How I can tell whether the username or the email in this scenario was the one that was found in the mongo database. I use `$or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]` to find an existing username or email but I need to know which one was found so I can send a message to the client to say the username is taken or the email is taken. I tried to log the "user" variable but it returned the object were it found the match.

```
User.findOne({
    $or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]
}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log('username or password is taken');
    } else {
      userDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    }
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `pre validate` hooks for validating unique `email` and `username`.

```
User.pre('validate', true, function validateUniqueEmail( next, done) {
    next(); 
    User.findOne({email: this.email}).exec(function(err, user) {


    if(err) {
    return done(err);
    }

    if(user) {

    return done(new Error('Email is taken'));
    }

    done();

    });


});


User.pre('validate', true, function validateUniqueUsername( next, done) {
    next();
    User.findOne({username: this.username}).exec(function(err, user) {


    if(err) {
    return done(err);
    }

    if(user) {

    return done(new Error('Username is taken'));
    }

    done();

    });


});
```

Comment: I ran into this error, User.pre('validate', true, function validateUniqueEmail( true, done) {
                                                         ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token true, It did not recognize the token true

Comment: I am not sure , when you return Error for a healthy situation.  will it work or not. and Evne IF it works, its not friendly method.

Comment: @enRaiser READ the documentation which says you MUST use instance of an Error object in there

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the user objet which is found.

```
  User.findOne({
     $or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]  
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
       if(user.username == req.body.username){
         console.log('username is taken');
       }else{
         console.log(' email is taken');
       }
  } else {
    userDetails.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
  if (err) {
     return done(err);
  }
});
```